# addMatrix() method

Tags: java, matrix, homework

Can anyone review my `addMatrix()` method to see if I am following the instructions correctly?

These are the instructions:

> This is a `public` method (I'm calling it `addMatrix()`) that has *only one parameter* for a `DoubleMatrix` to add this `doubMatrix` (not changing this `doubMatrix`) and the parameter's `doubMatrix` and return a new `DoubleMatrix` (you'll need a local 2-dim. array to store the result of adding and pass to the constructor).
>
> Make sure you check if the dimensions of this `doubMatrix` and the parameter's `doubMatrix` are the same (if not, return a new `DoubleMatrix` calling the first constructor passing 1, 1).

I think I wrote the part where it said calling first constructor passing 1,1 wrong.

```
package homework3;

public class DoubleMatrix
{
    private double[][] doubMatrix;

    public DoubleMatrix()
    {
        int row;
        int col;
        if(row > 0 && col > 0)
        {
            makeDoubMatrix(1,1);
        }
        else
        {
            row = 1;
            col = 1;
        }
    }
    
    public DoubleMatrix(double[][] tempArray) 
    {
        if(tempArray != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.length-1;i++)
            {
                if(tempArray[i].length == tempArray[i+1].length)
                {
                    doubMatrix = tempArray;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            makeDoubMatrix(1,1);
        }
    }
    
    public int getDim1()
    {
        return doubMatrix.length;
    }
    
    public int getDim2()
    {
        return doubMatrix[0].length;
    }
    
    private void makeDoubMatrix(int row, int col)
    {
        double[][] tempArray  = new double[row][col];
        for(int i = 0;i < tempArray.length;i++)
            for(int j = 0;j < tempArray[i].length;j++)
            {
                tempArray[i][j] = Math.random() * (100);            
            } //end for   
        tempArray = doubMatrix;
    }
    
    public double[][] addMatrix(double[][] doubMatrix)
    {    
        this. doubMatrix = doubMatrix;
        double[][] tempArray = null;
        if(this.doubMatrix.length == doubMatrix.length)
            if(this.doubMatrix[0].length == doubMatrix[0].length)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i< this.doubMatrix.length;i++)
                      for(int j = 0; j< this.doubMatrix[i].length;j++ )
                      {
                          tempArray[i][j] = this.doubMatrix[i][j] + doubMatrix[i][j];// add two matrices 
                      }//end for    
            }
            else
            {
                return  tempArray = new double[1][1];
            }
        
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, I would combine the size check conditional, and further, move it to it's own method to make the code a bit more clear. Working with objects (as @Alex suggested), will make this much easier:

```
if(this.doubMatrix.length == doubMatrix.length)
        if(this.doubMatrix[0].length == doubMatrix[0].length) {
    // stuff
}
```

Change to something like:

```
if(this.isSameSize(doubMatrix))
{
    //stuff
}

// ...
// later
public boolean isSameSize(DoubleMatrix doub) {
    return // Comparison of column and rows of backing arrays
}
```

- Also in your `addMatrix()` function, it looks like you are making some confusing/improper assignments:

  ```
  this.doubMatrix = doubMatrix
  ```

  ...is overwriting your current `DoubleMatrix` backing array with the one you
  are passing into the method (the `this` keyword refers to the class' scope, not the method's scope). I would suggest simply renaming the `addMatrix()` parameter to something else so you don't have the confusion of working with `this.doubMatrix` and `doubMatrix`.
- Your `addMatrix()` result array (`tempArray`) is also initialized to `null` and never properly initialized before you start placing values there. That's going to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 4):

1. I think you should operate your matrices as objects, not as two-dimensional arrays, so you could change your method

   ```
   public double[][] addMatrix(double[][] doubMatrix)
   ```

   to

   ```
   public DoubleMatrix add(DoubleMatrix secondMatrix)
   ```

   and use the object for further operations.
2. Then your method

   ```
   makeDoubleMatrix(int row, int col)
   ```

   could be just a constructor:

   ```
   public DoubleMatrix(int row, int col)
   ```
3. I really can't understand the purpose of the following code:

   ```
   int row;
   int col;
   if(row > 0 && col > 0)
   ```

   if you have no matrix params defined so:

   ```
   public DoubleMatrix(){
       this(1,1);
   }
   ```

   assuming that you will transform your `makeDoubleMatrix()` to constructor.
4. After all this your failed dimension check could just return `new DoubleMatrix()` which will construct and new a 1x1 `DoubleMatrix`.